# bmatrix vs \left[...\right]

Tags: equations, matrices

I following code produces matrices as given in image

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}} \mathbf{y}_1 \\ \vdots \\ \mathbf{y}_s \\ \vdots \\ \mathbf{y}_S \end{array}} \right] = 
        \begin{bmatrix}         \mathbf{y}_1 \\ \vdots \\ \mathbf{y}_s \\ \vdots \\ \mathbf{y}_S \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

To me the matrix produced by `bmatrix` (on the right) is a bit congested, is there a way to produce a spacious matrix (like in the left) using `bmatrix`?

Just curious :)

Thanks
[image]

Comment: Write `\,y_\,` for the first element (or whatever spacing command you please).

Comment: almost the only thing bmatrix does is remove that space so simpler to use left/right and matrix if you want the space

Comment: That’s the spacing most mathematics books use. By the way, why all those unnecessary braces? Typing `\mathbf{y}_1` is simpler and yields the same output.

Comment: I copied it from mathtype and modified it, math type puts so many braces. I should have removed them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want the space like in `array`, use `array`:

```
\renewenvironment{bmatrix}
  {\left[\array{*{\value{MaxMatrixCols}}{c}}}
  {\endarray\right]}
```

Full example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\renewenvironment{bmatrix}
  {\left[\array{*{\value{MaxMatrixCols}}{c}}}
  {\endarray\right]}

\begin{document}

\[
  \left[
    \begin{array}{ c }
      \mathbf{y}_1 \\ \vdots \\ \mathbf{y}_s \\ \vdots \\ \mathbf{y}_S
    \end{array}
  \right] =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \mathbf{y}_1 \\ \vdots \\ \mathbf{y}_s \\ \vdots \\ \mathbf{y}_S
  \end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

But, please, don't: the standard `\arraycolsep` is really too much. Maybe

```
\renewenvironment{bmatrix}
  {\left[\hspace{-.5\arraycolsep}\array{*{\value{MaxMatrixCols}}{c}}}
  {\endarray\hspace{-.5\arraycolsep}\right]}
```

which would yield

[image]

Actually, in order to get the same behavior as the standard `bmatrix`, one should add a small bit of code:

```
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{bmatrix}
  {\left[\let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar\array{*{\value{MaxMatrixCols}}{c}}}
  {\endarray\right]}
\makeatother
```

This allows a row to begin with `[` without taking special precautions.

Comment: This... seems... the... same... as... mine...

Comment: @Werner Not at all. You're adding space that then gets removed.

Comment: Tomato, tomato, tomato...

Answer (score 2):

The definition of `bmatrix` uses `\left[`...`\right]` but also removes the exterior space inserted by the `col`umn `sep`aration of the internal `array` (as part of `\env@matrix` and `\endmatrix`; see [`amsmath.dtx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amsmath/amsmath.dtx)). You can adjust this to suit your needs:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
% Original definition of bmatrix
% \newenvironment{bmatrix}{\left[\env@matrix}{\endmatrix\right]}
\renewenvironment{bmatrix}
  {\left[\hspace{\arraycolsep}\env@matrix}
  {\endmatrix\hspace{\arraycolsep}\right]}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
  \left[
    \begin{array}{ *{20}{c} }
      \mathbf{y}_1 \\ \vdots \\ \mathbf{y}_s \\ \vdots \\ \mathbf{y}_S
    \end{array}
  \right] = 
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \mathbf{y}_1 \\ \vdots \\ \mathbf{y}_s \\ \vdots \\ \mathbf{y}_S
  \end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I personally prefer something smaller than `\arraycolsep`. Maybe `.5\arraycolsep`.